# PostGIS: What is the difference between regular R-tree and R-tree on top of GiST?

Tags: postgis, java, rtree

I have built a spatial index structure that I am trying to compare with other existing spatial index structures. I have to either code (in Java) the same logic that PostGIS uses or find a java library that uses this logic (and I have been unable to find one).

PostGIS says that their spatial index structure is an [R-tree on top of GiST](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#gist_indexes).

I have read [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103647/does-postgis-have-separate-implementation-of-gist-index-from-postgresql).

I have 3 questions:

1) What is the main difference between a regular R-tree and an R-tree on top of GiST?

2) Do you know any disk-based R-tree libraries in Java? The ones I have found are in-memory R-trees.

3) If I were to find an R-tree implementation (or write on my own), how difficult is it to make this implementation into an "R-tree on top of GiST"? I know how R-trees work.

Comment: GIS.SE works on a "One question, best answer" basis, but you have three questions.  Please rewrite this question for your most pressing problem; you can always ask more questions later.