# PostGIS R-Tree: Why does it exist when PostgreSQL already implements its R-Tree with what appears to be the same algorithm?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, rtree, implementation

PostGIS implements its R-Tree algorithm via PostgreSQL's GiST. But [PostgreSQL already implements its R-Tree](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/2eb4a831e5fb5d8fc17e13aea56e04af3efe27b4/src/backend/access/gist/gistproc.c) and the logic appears almost identical to that [PostGIS is also implementing](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/postgis/gserialized_gist_2d.c).

So why are there 2 R-Trees in the PostgreSQL environment? 
I can think that it has to do with the fact that PostGIS offers additional data types. But was it really required that PostGIS adds its own (identical) R-Tree algorithm? It looks like redundant code to me (defining the same logic at two points). I can also think that there might have been differences in the past which required this inefficiency, but are they there now and so what would they be exactly?

Comment: Perhaps duplicate with an answer by a PostGIS developer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103647/does-postgis-have-separate-implementation-of-gist-index-from-postgresql

Comment: My question is actually a follow-up on the accepted answer; what is the scenario which requires PostGIS to implement its own R-Tree if PostgreSQL already implements it -- and both through GiST (so native R-Tree limitations are not relevant)?

Comment: Let's see if @Paul Ramsey reacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find there are multiple r-tree-over-gist implementations floating around. If you look in `contrib/cube` you'll find another one.

Fundamentally, the rtree-over-gist binding in core has not been built to be easy for extensions to make use of, it has been built for the type it supports: the internal `box` type.

That type differs from what's in PostGIS in a couple ways: it's a box, not a geometry; it assumes double precision, while PostGIS uses floats.

I suppose if the core code was generalized more, we could make use of it, maybe (the float/double issue might be insuperable). In addition to the 2D tree, which is quite similar, we also have an n-d tree, which is different (though it's similar to the `contrib/cube` implementation) and supports higher dimensional geometry indexing and geography indexing.

While DRY is a virtue in many cases, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with a little code copying. I found a wee bug in the core code back when I was code copying in the version under the 2.0 PostGIS release, thanks to having to read it very carefully while adapting it to our purposes for higher dimensionality.

Comment: Thank you for relevant information and incredible insights!

Answer (score 2):

From the [FAQ](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_FAQ.html),

> [**Why aren't PostgreSQL R-Tree indexes supported?**](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_FAQ.html#idm1122)
>
> Early versions of PostGIS used the PostgreSQL R-Tree indexes. However,
>   PostgreSQL R-Trees have been completely discarded since version 0.6,
>   and spatial indexing is provided with an R-Tree-over-GiST scheme.
>
> Our tests have shown search speed for native R-Tree and GiST to be
>   comparable. Native PostgreSQL R-Trees have two limitations which make
>   them undesirable for use with GIS features (note that these
>   limitations are due to the current PostgreSQL native R-Tree
>   implementation, not the R-Tree concept in general):
>
> - R-Tree indexes in PostgreSQL cannot handle features which are larger than 8K in size. GiST indexes can, using the "lossy" trick of substituting the bounding box for the feature itself.
> - R-Tree indexes in PostgreSQL are not "null safe", so building an index on a geometry column which contains null geometries will fail. [GiST indexes are null-safe]

The [TODO](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/bd3177743db5cb786deb05d7327f39a5cec2daf6/TODO) also has,

> Fast extent estimation based on reading the head of the R-Tree.

So presumably they're a work-in-progress and they don't want to be tied to CORE to get their stuff accepted.

I think for a [true explanation here you'd have to understand the commits and the differences.](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/commits/svn-trunk/postgis/gserialized_gist_2d.c)