# Spatial indexes with RTree for polygons

Tags: polygon, spatial-database, gis-principle, spatial-index, indexing

I am trying to understand about how R-tree works for polygon data. In other words, polygon is a list of vertices (points), however, I am wondering how spatial index can recognize the order of points in R-tree. For example, I have a table with thousands of polygons (MULTIPOLYGON (((385653.893 6671591.048, 385573...)))) which I would like to know the logic behind the spatial indexing for polygon that how to create a bounding box for these points as a polygon. Is there any ordering process?

I have searched a lot on the Internet but I could not find the answer of my question.

What is the structure of indexing for such geometries?

Comment: have you tried looking at the source code of an implementation

Comment: No, but I will try it. Do you think it would be helpful?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: You can either read technical papers describing R-Trees or actual code implementing them, which is more helpful depends on you and your end aim.

Comment: Thank you! I know my question is basic one, sorry about that. I have read technical papers about R-Trees like [this](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/SI-LS/papers/Gut84.pdf). Also, I am familiar with the structure.

Comment: Let me explain more about my problem. I have a polygon dataset and I want to query points inside and outside of polygons efficiently. If I use an index like r-tree to get a fast result, I would like to know how this index selects such points in polygon. There is some libraries in python to do indexing very easily, but I want to know it works. I have searched in github for implementation of r-tree like [this](https://github.com/Rhoana/pyrtree/blob/master/pyrtree/rtree.py), however, it's not helpful to understand how it works for polygons and how to separate the points.

Comment: Depending on your language there is almost certainly a pre-existing library for this to save you trying to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may find this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263370/postgis-r-tree-why-does-it-exist-when-postgresql-already-implements-its-r-tree) useful.  The key part is `GIST`. The bounding box of the geometry is indexed, and if a point is found - via the index - to be within the bounding box, then a real point-polygon intersection is computed using the real geometry. (and that's why is performs poorly on distant multi-polygons or on huge geometries)

Comment: Great. Thank you